# Realm, best approach to save\update\Observe String to Realm Object

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift

(looking for the best approach to save Realm property.

I have a UIViewController with a lot of TextView, etc that I fill from a Realm object.

Each time the textfield are modified, I need to send back to change un the realm property.

The (not cool) thing, are that I cannot save directly, I have to open a write transaction.

```
object.propertyA= “hello”    // crash

try! realm.write {      //work
        userBeer?.Name = lblbeerName.text!
}
```

So, i found a bit painfull (and not clean) to to that for all text.

I’ve looked at rxRealm, but cannot see any (newbies) sample to make that.

So, I have 2 approach un mind

1. Modify the model getters and setters for the property

   var beerName: String? {
           get {
               return self.Name
           }
           set  {
               try! realm.write {
               self.txtName=beerName!
           }
       }
2. use the RXSwift approach from here (https://www.raywenderlich.com/149753/bond-tutorial-bindings-swift)

   - Bing the TextField.text to a var String, and observe this string to write.

What do you think?

My perfect world will be to find a way to bing the TextField.text property directly, something like:
myRealmObject.property.BindTo(self.txtName)

Answer (score 1):

Katsumi from Realm here. Although it is not the best approach, I propose another way. You can use `realm.beginWrite()` and `try! realm.commitWrite()` instead of block-based API for a long-lived transaction.

For example, you can open a transaction when the view appeared, and then close the transaction when the view disappeared, like the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    realm.beginWrite()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    try! realm.commitWrite()
}
```

In this way, you can assign a value to the Realm object at any time in the view.
Be careful not to leave the transaction open. To avoid increasing file size, do not update data frequently in the background while transactions are open.

Answer (score 0):

Change the property within the `write` block:

```
try! realm.write {
    object.propertyA = “hello”
    userBeer?.Name = lblbeerName.text!
}
```